# Add ToolStripMenuItem in new row when one row is filled inside ToolStrip

Tags: c#, toolstrip, toolstripmenu

I have one form and inside form i have one toolstrip control, and i am adding ToolStripMenuItem dynamically.
What i want is when one is filled up, items should list in next row.
I tried this for increasing the height and width of form  but adding items in new row not happening.

```
 ToolStripItemCollection t_col = toolStripTaskBar.Items;
        int _howMany = t_col.Count;
        Rectangle mi_bounds = t_col[_howMany - 1].Bounds;
        if (this.Width < (mi_bounds.X + mi_bounds.Width))
        {
            int minimumFormHeight = 80;
            this.MinimumSize = new Size((mi_bounds.X + mi_bounds.Width), minimumFormHeight);

        }
```

Let me know if you not understand what i want.

Any suggestion how can i achieve this.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LayoutStyle property of ToolStrip. You need to set up it to Table and modify layout settings (specify rows and columns count).

You can do it like this:

```
this.toolStrip1.LayoutStyle = ToolStripLayoutStyle.Table;
var layoutSettings = (this.toolStrip1.LayoutSettings as TableLayoutSettings);
layoutSettings.ColumnCount = 3;
layoutSettings.RowCount = 3;
```

And the you can add new items to toolstrip:

```
var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(string.Format("item{0}", this.toolStrip1.Items.Count + 1));
this.toolStrip1.Items.Add(item);
```